# Is $\mathcal C^1([a,b],\mathbb R)$ endowed with the $C^1$-norm a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $\mathcal C^1([a,b],\mathbb R)$ be endowed with the $C^1$-norm $\|\cdot\|$ where $\|f\| = \| f \|_\infty + \| f' \|_\infty$ for $f \in \mathcal C^1([a,b],\mathbb R)$.

In class, we have proved that $\langle \mathcal C^1([a,b],\mathbb R), \|\cdot\| \rangle$ is a Banach space. I could not figure out if $\langle \mathcal C^1([a,b],\mathbb R), \|\cdot\| \rangle$ is a Hilbert space or not. In other words, I'm not sure if $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by some inner product.

Could you please shed me some light on this issue? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check the parallelogram identity.

Comment: Hi @amsmath, I've tried to use the parallelogram identity, but I don't know if there exist functions $f,g$ that violate the parallelogram identity.

Comment: Hint: there surely are.

Comment: Check for example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also, you can check that the minimum principle fails in $C^1$, while it holds in every Hilbert space. That is, there exist non-empty closed convex sets in $C^1$ which have no vector of minimal norm (in contrast to Hilbert spaces), and/or have more than one such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $[a,b]=[0,1]$ set $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1$. Then
$$
\|f-g\|^2+\|f+g\|^2 = (\|x-1\|_\infty + 1)^2 + (\|x+1\|_\infty + 1)^2 = 4+9=13.
$$
But
$$
2\|f\|^2+2\|g\|^2 = 2(1+1)^2 + 2 = 10.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!, I just did the calculation and cross-check it with your answer :))